# Unable to access the dashboard using minikube dashboard command

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, minikube

[image: This is the command I used and the output I got after using the minikube dashboard command]

[image: This is the error I am getting while accessing the url.]

I was trying to access the dashboard by using the command minikube dashboard and I also got the url to access that but while accessing it I was getting the error.
I am using AWS ubuntu Instance and below are rules of the SG.

[image: This is the Security group I am using for the instance.]

If you want to know anymore information about it please ask...
Thank You.

Comment: That url seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I get that url from the command minikube dashboard so I don't know if it is correct or not.

Comment: Did you run ```minikube tunnel```?
I've needed that when my urls are going to 127.0.0.1 instead of to the minikube IP.